# gulp watch stopped working all of a sudden

Tags: drupal, gulp-watch, lando

I inherited a codebase and gulp was happily compiling my scss files. It suddenly stopped working with the message `Local gulp not found in /app/path/to/theme/scss. Try running: npm install gulp`. `gulp -v` says `CLI version: 2.3.0, Local version: Unknown`. How do I get my gulp watch back? Below is my .lando.yml

```
name: dev-kriens
recipe: drupal9
config:
  webroot: web
  php: '8.1'
  composer_version: '2.5.8'
events:
  post-start:
    - appserver: cp -r /tmp/auth.json /var/www/.composer/auth.json
    - appserver: file /var/www/.composer/auth.json
services:
  appserver:
    volumes:
      - ../auth.json:/tmp/auth.json
  node:
    type: node:18
    build:
      - npm install
      - gulp
    globals:
      gulp-cli: latest
  mailhog:
    type: mailhog
    hogfrom:
      - appserver
tooling:
  npm:
    service: node
  node:
    service: node
  gulp:
    service: node
  yarn:
    service: node
  drush:
    service: appserver
    cmd:
      - "drush --root=/app/web"
  composer:
    service: appserver
    cmd:
      - "php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer --working-dir=/app"
```

I did a `npm i install` even though not needed, because it was working previously. I also did `lando destroy`, `lando rebuild`

Comment: need to share all of your gulp-file